# Re-render behaviour of container and subcomponents

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

I have the following data structure:

fruits: [apple:4,pear:3,banana:5] in a reducer.
With reduxToolkit I've definited both a getFruitsQuery and a getFruitQuery(id)
There is also a FruitMutation.

Now, on the rendering side, I have a list component that uses as datasource the fruits reducers, and each element of the list is a component in itself.

The biggest problem that I have is that, when I trigger a mutation on a single fruit, the entire list (with all the subelement) gets re-rendered.
Is there a more efficient way to handle this to avoid all those re-renders ?

Comment: Have you used the invalidTags?

Comment: I have,  I have two tags, one call Fruits and the other Fruit. And I invalidate Fruit when the mutation is called

Comment: I think you should use memo to wrap you fruit Component.So when one fruit update,of course the fruits list will update.So it will trigger re-render.As only one fruit changes,the other fruits will not re-render.If you don't,it will. ProvideTags only solve the network cache problem,not the re-render problem of react.

Comment: ok, that helps understand. I have no idea what Memo is. Do you mind provide a link ?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo